# Uploading large number of photos

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, ftp

I have this requirement of Uploading 1000s of Photos from a window application.

Logic tht i am following is..First the photos are resized in local box and then uploaded.

I have tried using FTP upload as well as Http upload using Web service in dotnet..

But the best solution i got is...its taking 100 min to upload 1000 photos.
i.e. 1 min to upload 10 photos.

Can any one suggest what else can be a possible try to improve the performance here.

Lemme know if more details required..

Comment: What format are your photos? what is the bandwidth that you have? If these photos are too large, then perhaps this is the problem.

Comment: you can use threads to upload more than one photo at a time and by using thread your uploading speed will be increased....

Comment: @Andrew I have tested this app in different machine..but the Performance im getting is low..so bandwidth is not a problem here...

photos are JPG with 800*600  ...each image is of aronud 50kb

Comment: @GauravAgrawal ..yes.you are correct..i have Threading implemented..the time its taking after that..forgot to mention tht

Comment: If your (free) bandwidth is 7kbps (kilo bits per second), then what you described is just about the maximum bandwidth capacity.  Depending on the usage of the network and other factors, this may be a problem - try taking a speed test just to make sure that bandwidth is not the issue. A statement that bandwidth is not an issue because performance is low is not a convincing argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the bandwidth required, there's an overhead in uploading one file at a time. You could try zipping them all to a single file (even though with many image formats the size saving won't be significant) and uploading in that way, to avoid the file-by-file overhead. Or even batching them, say 50 or 100 photos to a zip file.

Comment: This a good approach but has a draw back, that is if the uploading is interrupted by any mean like disconnection, the complete batch has to uploaded again. but in case of file to file upload only a single file will have to uploaded.
I think it also depends on the reliability of the network, if the network is reliable than the uploading in batches is suitable.

Comment: @David..that is one solution i had been suggested..but u know it was not helping that great..but this is one case to be checked i.e. batching way..

I know that the overhead is more in case of FTP as it will do take care of connection each time for each image..so i followed HTTP post method.

Comment: When choosing a compression algorithm find one that is efficient and fast over one that has good compression ability - you will hardly get any size improvement for .jpg files but at least you will take too long to do so. A better approach to actually zipping files is to combine them (as in the case with .tar files).

Comment: @David..though its a way to zip a file and FTP it..but it dint help in faster uploading rather it made it slower than before.

Please suggest if any other option that might give performance here..

Answer (score 0):

First re-size the photos and upload the photos in a batch. No one can increase the bandwidth. You can use H.264 image compression technique for reliability and consistency for different browsers.

[H.264 for image compression](http://H.264%20for%20image%20compression)

[How to implement H.264 in c# Sample1](http://jasonjano.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ffmpeg/)

[How to implement H.264 in c# Sample 2](http://nolovelust.com/post/Another-Simple-C-Wrapper-For-FFmpeg.aspx)

Comment: i am not sure about wat is flash type upload..

wat i am basically searching here is a LOGIC..Like David gave a suggestion of zipping them all...that is one case of improving performance..but i believe then there we loose Threading use..

Answer (score 0):

I have been working in implementing a solution to maximize transfer speeds when moving big files through WAN's. Take in account that the limiting factor in speed through WAN's is not bandwidth but latency and TCP window size. Maybe this is the issue you are experiencing?: [See explanation here](http://www.speedguide.net/articles/the-tcp-window-latency-and-the-bandwidth-delay-2678)

Using FTP transmissions in parallel should improve your performance, and you wouldn't need to implement a solution by hand. Does your FTP support sending a file by multiple connections?

I developed my own solution using a pool of async sockets and a custom protocol. The speeds improved a lot compared to FTP, but it was no a trivial development...

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by ensuring that both operations were being carried out asynchronously and use some sort of messaging between the two.  So as images are processed they're added to the message queue for uploading.  Once they've been uploaded they're removed from the queue.  That way if something goes wrong you'll not have to reload all of them again.  Which is also an issue I'd have with doing batch uploads.